# Unable to see visual studio option 'Web Projects'

Tags: visual-studio-2010, wcf

I am using VS 2010, and I would like to configure my WCF project to use IIS. However, in VS 2010 > Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions, I don't see the Web Projects option area.

[image: My VS2010]

My co-worker's computer shows the following under Projects and Solutions:

[image: My Co-worker's VS2010]

What do I need to do to enable this option in my VS 2010 install?  I just re-installed from the same VS2010 bin as my co-worker to no effect.

Comment: You possibly need to download [VS 2010 SP 1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2011/03/14/enabling-iis-express-support-in-vs-2010-sp1.aspx) and install [IIS Express](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/vs-2010-sp1-beta-and-iis-developer-express). Latest [IIS Express here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-za/download/details.aspx?id=34679)

Comment: Yes, that was it. I thought I already had VS SP1 installed, but upon re-installing it, I was able to see the option.